# How to "download Cordova" and "expand appropriate archive"?

Tags: android, cordova

Cordova's Android Platform Guide states:

> Install Cordova Shell Tools
>
> If you want to use Cordova's Android-centered shell tools in
>   conjunction with the SDK, download Cordova from cordova.apache.org.
>   Otherwise ignore this section if you plan to use the cross-platform
>   CLI tool described in The Command-Line Interface.
>
> The Cordova download contains separate archives for each platform. Be
>   sure to expand the appropriate archive, android in this case, within
>   an empty directory. The relevant executible utilities are available in
>   the top-level bin directory. (Consult the README file if necessary for
>   more detailed directions.)

However, cordova.apache.org only offers "npm install -g cordova" as a means to get and install cordova, and there is no mention of how to download it separately to get at the "Shell Tools".

What have I missed?

Comment: the cordova android source code is here https://github.com/apache/cordova-android

Comment: Hi, thanks, that helped.  If only the docs added that clue...